# Symfony 3 Custom Form Password Authenticator

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I'm trying to authenticating via the **Custom Form Password Authenticator**, I follow the Symfony Example at this page: [Custom Form Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html), I changed a few snippet for put my authentication logic. All seem to work perfectly... But Symfony continued telling me that I'm authenticated as anonymous... Here is the code:

**My Custom Athenticator:**

```
class SippyAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $sippyAccounts;

    public function __construct(SippyAccounts $sippyAccounts)
    {
        $this->sippyAccounts = $sippyAccounts;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $result = $this->sippyAccounts->login($token->getUsername(), $token->getCredentials());

        if($result->isError()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        } else {
            $roles = array('ROLE_ACCOUNT');
            $user = new User($token->getUsername(), $token->getCredentials(), $roles);

            $tokenNew = new UsernamePasswordToken( $user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
            return $tokenNew;
        }
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

**This is my security.yml:**

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            simple_form:
                authenticator: sippy.authenticator
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/es/overview, roles: ROLE_ACCOUNT }
```

Comment: Can you find anything related in Symfony's error log? Does `$user->getRoles()` contain anything? Does `$sippyAccounts->login()` execute successfully?

Comment: Thanks for respond... There is nothing in the error logs and $sippyAccounts->login() execute successfully... all execute normal without error... Just a few minutes ago i resolve the problem... It was because i'm generating the user without call the $userProvider object, and it seem that symfony call this object ($userProvider) for populate the session with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was generating the **User** object without call the $userProvider (because I didn't implement it), and symfony later use this object ($userProvider) to retrive the already autenticated user and put it in the session... Below the **UserProvider** class and the modified **SippyAuthenticator**:

```
class SippyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $sippyAccounts;

    public function __construct(SippyAccounts $sippyAccounts)
    {
        $this->sippyAccounts = $sippyAccounts;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $result = $this->sippyAccounts->informationByUsername($username);

        if (!$result->isError()) {
            $password = null;
            return new SippyUser($username, $password, null, array('ROLE_ACCOUNT'));
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof SippyUser) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
            );
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'AppBundle\Model\SippyUser';
    }
}

class SippyAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $sippyAccounts;

    public function __construct(SippyAccounts $sippyAccounts)
    {
        $this->sippyAccounts = $sippyAccounts;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $result = $this->sippyAccounts->login($token->getUsername(), $token->getCredentials());

        if($result->isError()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
        } else {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());

            $tokenNew = new UsernamePasswordToken( $user, $user->getPassword(), $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
            $tokenNew->setAttributes($token->getAttributes());
            return $tokenNew;
        }
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }
}
```

I hope this answer helpful to someone else...